# Не могу закодировать SHA1 в Base64

Tags: php, java, base64, sha1

Есть такая строка захэшированная в  SHA1 - `5e043deb305209e9698d9630827a99e977017622`

нужно взять ее  base64

делаю так `String s1 = Base64.encodeBase64String(s.getBytes());`

получаю это: `NWUwNDNkZWIzMDUyMDllOTY5OGQ5NjMwODI3YTk5ZTk3NzAxNzYyMg`

В API предоставленном мне сторонним разработчиком из этой строки получается другой  base64 `XgQ96zBSCelpjZYwgnqZ6XcBdiI=`
Помогите понять, как это у него получается другой  base64. его пример на  php
скорее всего высчитывается так 
`$hash = base64_encode(pack('H*',$str));`

как сделать на  Java  то же самое?

Comment: А вы как получили SHA-1 ? он у вас в шестнадцетиричном виде. А его надо получить в сыром бинарном виде

Comment: Вот у http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sha1.php есть второй параметр, его true даете и получаете sha-1 в сыром виде

Comment: я что просил получить  SHA1 в сыром виде? У меня есть строка. я ее шифрую в  SHA1. И php и  Java  шифруют его одинаково и я получаю одинаковые строки зашифрованные в  SHA1. Но когда я ЭТУ ЗАШИФРОВАННУЮ В SHA1 строку пытаюсь зашифровать в base64  то результат разный

Comment: Вы в base64 переводите шестнадцедиричное представление SHA-1, а судя по длине той строки которая нужна вам надо кодировать в base64 то же самое значение sha-1 но представленное в сыром виде. Да, вы можете конечно получить его pack, но проще сразу получить его в подходящем виде на этапе получения самого sha-1

Comment: @Mike где-то был ответ про отличия байтов, строк и чисел. IMHO, надо сюда...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHA1 - не шифрование, а хэширование. Base64 - тоже не шифрование, а кодирование. Полученные вами данные NWUwNDNkZWI... - корректны.
Декодирование XgQ96zBSCelpjZYwgnqZ6XcBdiI= дает результат 5e043d..., но только в виде байтов, а не строки. Соответственно, вам нужно на вход base64 подавать сырые данные, а не в виде строки.

Comment: может вы приглядитесь к вопросу и увидете  Base64.encodeBase64String(s.getBytes()); - s.getBytes().

Я просто вставляю строку в онлайн  php и он мне выводит XgQ96zBSCelpjZYwgnqZ6XcBdiI= но когда в java  то выводит NWUwNDNkZWIzMDUyMDllOTY5OGQ5NjMwODI3YTk5ZTk3NzAxNzYyMg

Comment: @user5620472 может вы приглядитесь к ответу и прочтете какие ИМЕННО данные нужно подать на вход bsde64, чтобы получить приведенные вами base64-кодированные строки?

Comment: @user5620472 писать код вы можете сколько угодно. Есть байты, base64 оперирует именно с байтами. И пока вы этого не поймете - будете мучаться.

Comment: спасибо. решил. я думал что getBytes() и есть сырые данные